Red neuronal mlp
Necesito ayuda en cuanto a un proyecto algo complejo, estoy creando una red neuronal MLP en javascript y html sin usar dependencias ni node.js.
Ya he creado una clase llamada NeuralNetwork, en ella escribí los métodos Predict y Train, además de definir la capa de entrada, capa oculta y la de salida.
El problema está en el método Train, he intentado varios algoritmos como el desvanecimiento del gradiente y función de costo MSE para medir el error.
En este caso ninguna me ha funcionado, si alguien puede implementar un buen backpropagation este es el código:
class NeuralNetwork {

    constructor(inputSize, hiddenSize, outputSize) {
        this.inputSize = inputSize;
        this.hiddenSize = hiddenSize;
        this.outputSize = outputSize;

        this.inputNeurons = new Array(this.inputSize).fill().map(() => {
            return {
                value: 0,
                weights: new Array(this.hiddenSize).fill().map(() => Math.random())
            };
        });

        this.hiddenPerceptrons = new Array(this.hiddenSize).fill().map(() => {
            return {
                value: 0,
                bias: Math.random(),
                weights: new Array(this.outputSize).fill().map(() => Math.random())
            };
        });

        this.outputNeurons = new Array(this.outputSize).fill().map(() => {
            return {
                value: 0,
                bias: Math.random()
            };
        });

        this.learningRate = 0.5;

    }

    ReLU(value) {
        return Math.max(0, value);
    }

    ReLU_Derivate(value) {
        return value > 0 ? 1 : 0
    }

    MSE(expecteds, predictions) {
        var error = 0;
        const m = expecteds.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            error += Math.pow(predictions[i] - expecteds[i], 2);
        }
        return error / m;
    }

    Predict(inputs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.inputSize; i++) {
            this.inputNeurons[i].value = inputs[i];
        }

        for (var h = 0; h < this.hiddenSize; h++) {
            var sum = this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].bias;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.inputSize; i++) {
                sum += this.inputNeurons[i].value * this.inputNeurons[i].weights[h];
            }
            this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].value = this.ReLU(sum);
        }

        for (var o = 0; o < this.outputSize; o++) {
            var sum = this.outputNeurons[o].bias;
            for (var h = 0; h < this.hiddenSize; h++) {
                sum += this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].value * this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].weights[o];
            }
            this.outputNeurons[o].value = this.ReLU(sum);
        }

        const results = new Array(this.outputSize).fill().map((_, i) => this.outputNeurons[i].value);

        return results;
    }

    Train(data, epochs) {
        const m = data.input.length; // Número de muestras en el dataset
    
        for (var epoch = 0; epoch < epochs; epoch++) {
            for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                // Paso 1: Forward propagation para obtener predicciones
                const prediction = this.Predict(data.input[i]);
    
                // Paso 2: Backpropagation para ajustar pesos y biases
    
                // Calcular el error de salida
                var outputErrors = new Array(this.outputSize).fill(0);
                for (var o = 0; o < this.outputSize; o++) {
                    outputErrors[o] = data.output[i][o] - prediction[o]; // Error: esperado - predicho
                }
    
                // Calcular gradientes y ajustar pesos de la capa oculta a la salida
                var hiddenErrors = new Array(this.hiddenSize).fill(0);
                for (var o = 0; o < this.outputSize; o++) {
                    var gradient = outputErrors[o] * this.ReLU_Derivate(this.outputNeurons[o].value);
                    for (var h = 0; h < this.hiddenSize; h++) {
                        // Ajustar peso de la conexión entre capa oculta y salida
                        this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].weights[o] += this.learningRate * gradient * this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].value;
    
                        // Acumular error para la capa oculta
                        hiddenErrors[h] += gradient * this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].weights[o];
                    }
    
                    // Ajustar el bias de la neurona de salida
                    this.outputNeurons[o].bias += this.learningRate * gradient;
                }
    
                // Calcular gradientes y ajustar pesos de la capa de entrada a la capa oculta
                for (var h = 0; h < this.hiddenSize; h++) {
                    var gradient = hiddenErrors[h] * this.ReLU_Derivate(this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].value);
                    for (var i = 0; i < this.inputSize; i++) {
                        // Ajustar peso de la conexión entre capa de entrada y capa oculta
                        this.inputNeurons[i].weights[h] += this.learningRate * gradient * this.inputNeurons[i].value;
                    }
    
                    // Ajustar el bias de la neurona oculta
                    this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].bias += this.learningRate * gradient;
                }
            }
    
            // Calcular y mostrar el error después de cada época (opcional)
            if (epoch % 10000 == 0) {
                var predictions = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                    predictions.push(this.Predict(data.input[i]));
                }
                const error = this.MSE(data.output, predictions);
                console.log(`Epoch ${epoch}, Error: ${error}`);
            }
        }
    }
}


En este caso ninguna me ha funcionado esto que quiere decir??? hay algun error en el lenguaje o de lógica o no hace lo que esperas?

Cuando digo que no me funcionaron ninguna de las dos me refería a que no supe implementarlas como se debe

entonces no es un problema de programación ... es un problema de conocimiento y estudio ... en ese caso tendrias que averiguar un tutorial o algo en donde te lo expliquen, lamentablemente aquí no te ayudaran con ese tipo de preguntas.

a simple vista veo problema con la inicializacion de los pesos, la elección de la tasa de aprendizaje, o la implementación del backpropagation. ya te lo muestro ...

Tienes algunos errores puntuales de implementación:

Errores acumulados: La forma de calcular los errores para las capas
intermedias puede ser incorrecta, ya que se están acumulando sin
tener en cuenta que los pesos también están siendo actualizados en
cada paso.

Optimización del cálculo del gradiente: Reemplazaremos algunas
operaciones para garantizar que la actualización sea consistente y
estable si no se vuelve un quilombo (problema).

Normalización opcional: Aseguraremos de que los datos de entrada estén
normalizados para evitar problemas con los gradientes, este es otro quilombo (problema).


Código optimizado:


class NeuralNetwork {

    constructor(inputSize, hiddenSize, outputSize) {
        this.inputSize = inputSize;
        this.hiddenSize = hiddenSize;
        this.outputSize = outputSize;

        // Inicializar las neuronas y sus pesos
        this.inputNeurons = Array.from({ length: this.inputSize }, () => ({
            value: 0,
            weights: Array.from({ length: this.hiddenSize }, () => Math.random() * 2 - 1)
        }));

        this.hiddenPerceptrons = Array.from({ length: this.hiddenSize }, () => ({
            value: 0,
            bias: Math.random() * 2 - 1,
            weights: Array.from({ length: this.outputSize }, () => Math.random() * 2 - 1)
        }));

        this.outputNeurons = Array.from({ length: this.outputSize }, () => ({
            value: 0,
            bias: Math.random() * 2 - 1
        }));

        this.learningRate = 0.1;
    }

    sigmoid(value) {
        return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-value));
    }

    sigmoidDerivative(value) {
        return value * (1 - value);
    }

    Predict(inputs) {
        // Capa de entrada
        for (let i = 0; i < this.inputSize; i++) {
            this.inputNeurons[i].value = inputs[i];
        }

        // Capa oculta
        for (let h = 0; h < this.hiddenSize; h++) {
            let sum = this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].bias;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.inputSize; i++) {
                sum += this.inputNeurons[i].value * this.inputNeurons[i].weights[h];
            }
            this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].value = this.sigmoid(sum);
        }

        // Capa de salida
        for (let o = 0; o < this.outputSize; o++) {
            let sum = this.outputNeurons[o].bias;
            for (let h = 0; h < this.hiddenSize; h++) {
                sum += this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].value * this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].weights[o];
            }
            this.outputNeurons[o].value = this.sigmoid(sum);
        }

        return this.outputNeurons.map(neuron => neuron.value);
    }

    Train(data, epochs) {
        const m = data.input.length; // Número de muestras

        for (let epoch = 0; epoch < epochs; epoch++) {
            let totalError = 0;

            for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                // Paso 1: Forward propagation
                const prediction = this.Predict(data.input[i]);

                // Paso 2: Calcular errores en la salida
                const outputErrors = prediction.map((pred, o) => {
                    const error = data.output[i][o] - pred;
                    totalError += Math.pow(error, 2);
                    return error * this.sigmoidDerivative(pred);
                });

                // Paso 3: Backpropagation para la capa oculta
                const hiddenErrors = Array.from({ length: this.hiddenSize }, (_, h) =>
                    outputErrors.reduce((sum, outputError, o) =>
                        sum + outputError * this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].weights[o], 0)
                    * this.sigmoidDerivative(this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].value)
                );

                // Actualizar pesos y biases entre capa oculta y salida
                for (let o = 0; o < this.outputSize; o++) {
                    for (let h = 0; h < this.hiddenSize; h++) {
                        this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].weights[o] +=
                            this.learningRate * outputErrors[o] * this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].value;
                    }
                    this.outputNeurons[o].bias += this.learningRate * outputErrors[o];
                }

                // Actualizar pesos y biases entre entrada y capa oculta
                for (let h = 0; h < this.hiddenSize; h++) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < this.inputSize; i++) {
                        this.inputNeurons[i].weights[h] +=
                            this.learningRate * hiddenErrors[h] * this.inputNeurons[i].value;
                    }
                    this.hiddenPerceptrons[h].bias += this.learningRate * hiddenErrors[h];
                }
            }

            // Mostrar el error total al final de cada época
            if (epoch % 1000 === 0) {
                console.log(`Epoch ${epoch}, Error total: ${totalError / m}`);
            }
        }
    }
}

const nn = new NeuralNetwork(2, 4, 1);

const trainingData = {
    input: [
        [0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 1]
    ],
    output: [
        [0],
        [1],
        [1],
        [0]
    ]
};

nn.Train(trainingData, 10000);

console.log({'label':'Debería estar cerca de 0','result' : nn.Predict([0, 0])});
console.log({'label':'Debería estar cerca de 0','result' : nn.Predict([1, 1])});
console.log({'label':'Debería estar cerca de 1','result' : nn.Predict([0, 1])});
console.log({'label':'Debería estar cerca de 1','result' : nn.Predict([1, 0])});



